# GTM compile error : Error at line 47, character 5: Parse error. ')' expected

Tags: jquery, google-tag-manager

I am having trouble compiling simple jQuery code in GTM. The error is:

> character 5: Parse error. ')' expected

```js
(function() {
  var previous_val;
  var next_val;
  $("#InstallmentsPart_InstallmentFrequency").on('focus', function() {
    previous_val = this.value;
  }).change(function() {
    next_val = this.value;
    return next_val;
  });
})();
```

Comment: The code you've shown is syntactically valid and is not the cause of the error

Comment: Is this a custom HTML tag or a custom javascript variable?

Comment: @kgrg thanks for your help. This is a custom javascript variable. i got it to compile without any errors by dropping the round bracket at the start and the colon and two round brackets at the end. however the code did not run, in sense it did not throw out any values, which is what i am looking at. the code that compiled looks like this

Comment: You should move the code to a custom HTML tag, and define the pages (triggers) where it should be run. In this case, your original code should be fine, wrapped in a script tag. The custom javascript function is not invoked, unless you use it in your other tags or variables.